# SQL [Tidyquery in R] - How to add BETWEEN dates along with existing AND condition?

Tags: sql, r

I'm using a tidyquery library in R to run SQL queries on my dataframe.
I'd like to keep the existing condition for Category but add a BETWEEN for end date i.e.
`Actual date` is BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'

How can I do this?
Thanks.
Edit:
Original query

```
new_data <-query("SELECT `Actual date`, `Order Number`, Category, 
COUNT_DISTINCT (`Order Number`) AS tran_count,
SUM (Quantity) AS items_purchased FROM data
WHERE Category LIKE 'Flavour%' AND
`Actual date`>= '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY `Actual date`, `Order Number`, Category")
```

When I try to amend the original query, it fails with Warning: `In dplyr::between(`Actual date`, "2021-01-01", "2021-01-31") : NAs introduced by coercion` and my dataframe becomes empty...

```
new_data <-query("SELECT `Actual date`, `Order Number`, Category, 
COUNT_DISTINCT (`Order Number`) AS tran_count,
SUM (Quantity) AS items_purchased FROM data
WHERE Category LIKE 'Flavour%' AND
(`Actual date` BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31')
GROUP BY `Actual date`, `Order Number`, Category")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL BETWEEN clause is implemented through a call to the between function of dplyr, which unfortunately doesn't work with strings and the date litterals you pass in your call are intrepreted as strings.
You must convert them into date explicitely in the SQL query:

An example with a simple dataset of mines

```
query("SELECT * FROM df1 WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-03'")
```

```
# A tibble: 0 x 4
# ... with 4 variables: date <date>, dc <dbl>, rea <dbl>, hosp <dbl>
Messages d'avis :
1: Dans dplyr::between(date, "2021-01-01", "2021-01-03") :
  NAs introduits lors de la conversion automatique
2: Dans dplyr::between(date, "2021-01-01", "2021-01-03") :
  NAs introduits lors de la conversion automatique
```

```
query("SELECT * FROM df1 WHERE date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021-01-01') AND TO_DATE('2021-01-03')")
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date          dc   rea  hosp
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-01-01 44959  2609 24263
2 2021-01-02 45115  2632 24458
3 2021-01-03 45231  2665 24780
```

Comment: Super! Thanks, @Nicolas2. I have added your solution in the original one to help others as well.